# Catching an API call from Azure AD B2C where the return status is not 200

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I can call my API's from B2C and can react to output claims e.g. where an output claim of isValid = false. I can then invoke a suitable user journey.

If the API itself returns an error e.g. status 409 = Conflict, this error is displayed on the B2C page.

How do I catch a situation where there is an error calling the API e.g. the API doesn't exist or is down? In such a case, the return status would be something other than 200.

But there doesn't seem to be a way to get at the return status as it is not an output claim?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe you can "catch" a non-successful invocation *of* the REST API.

If the REST API is unavailable or it isn't found, then IEF will either display an error message to the end user or return an error response to the end application.

If you can otherwise catch a failure condition in the REST API, then you can return a `409 Conflict` response with an error code in the response body.

Comment: Thanks, would be really useful if a status flag was returned for API calls.