# Rest validation error is not displayed in UI

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have written a test service to return Http Bad request to trigger the error. I am trying to call it from B2C. But the userMessage is **NOT** being displayed. It **continues** with other validation. What did I do wrong?

Postman testing for my test service. I return Bad Request.

[image]

Here is how I define in B2C to call that test service. The request is same as Postman testing.

```
     <ClaimType Id="testRequestBodyClaimType">
        <DisplayName>REST request body</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
      </ClaimType>


      <ClaimsTransformation Id="testGenerateJsonPayloadTransformation" TransformationMethod="GenerateJson">
        <InputParameters>
          <InputParameter Id="version" DataType="string" Value="1.0.0" />
          <InputParameter Id="status" DataType="string" Value="409" />
          <InputParameter Id="userMessage" DataType="string" Value="Your error message 2" />
        </InputParameters>
        <OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="testRequestBodyClaimType" TransformationClaimType="outputClaim" />
        </OutputClaims>
      </ClaimsTransformation>


        <TechnicalProfile Id="REST-Test">
          <DisplayName>Check Azure Function web hook testing test</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="ServiceUrl">https://xxxx.azurewebsites.net/api/myTest</Item>
            <Item Key="AuthenticationType">Bearer</Item>
            <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">Body</Item>
            <Item Key="ClaimUsedForRequestPayload">testRequestBodyClaimType</Item>
          </Metadata>
            <CryptographicKeys>
              <Key Id="BearerAuthenticationToken" StorageReferenceId="xxxx" />
            </CryptographicKeys>
          <InputClaimsTransformations>
            <InputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="testGenerateJsonPayloadTransformation" />
          </InputClaimsTransformations>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="testRequestBodyClaimType" />
          </InputClaims>
        </TechnicalProfile>
```

Here is logging from application insight.

```
                {
                  "Key": "TechnicalProfileEnabled",
                  "Value": {
                    "EnabledRule": "Always",
                    "EnabledResult": true,
                    "TechnicalProfile": "REST-Test"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "Key": "ValidationTechnicalProfile",
                  "Value": {
                    "Values": [
                      {
                        "Key": "TechnicalProfileId",
                        "Value": "REST-Test"
                      },
                      {
                        "Key": "ClaimsTransformation",
                        "Value": {
                          "Values": [
                            {
                              "Key": "Id",
                              "Value": "testGenerateJsonPayloadTransformation"
                            },
                            {
                              "Key": "InputParameter",
                              "Value": {
                                "Id": "version",
                                "Value": "1.0.0"
                              }
                            },
                            {
                              "Key": "InputParameter",
                              "Value": {
                                "Id": "status",
                                "Value": "409"
                              }
                            },
                            {
                              "Key": "InputParameter",
                              "Value": {
                                "Id": "userMessage",
                                "Value": "Your error message 2"
                              }
                            },
                            {
                              "Key": "Result",
                              "Value": {
                                "PolicyClaimType": "testRequestBodyClaimType",
                                "Value": "{\"version\":\"1.0.0\",\"status\":\"409\",\"userMessage\":\"Your error message 2\"}"
                              }
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        "Key": "MappingPartnerTypeForClaim",
                        "Value": {
                          "PartnerClaimType": "testRequestBodyClaimType",
                          "PolicyClaimType": "testRequestBodyClaimType"
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54437082/9922

Comment: Thanks. I figured it out. I need to return 409. The document is not very clear on this.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer after more testing.

According to document here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/restful-technical-profile

> **Returning validation error message**
>
> Your REST API may need to return an error message, such as 'The user
> was not found in the CRM system'. If an error occurs, the REST API
> should return an HTTP 4xx error message, such as, 400 (bad request),
> or 409 (conflict) response status code. The response body contains
> error message formatted in JSON:

But 400 (bad request) doesn't work. Once I updated to return **409 (conflict)** as http response, I can see the error being displayed.

```
              {
                  "Key": "Exception",
                  "Value": {
                    "Kind": "Handled",
                    "HResult": "80131500",
                    "Message": "ErrorCodes: AADB2C",
                    "Data": {
                      "IsPolicySpecificError": false
                    }
                  }
                }
```

[image]